# Update Object value from Array of Objects Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have a query result in values `$some = $query->result()` , now `$some[0]` should be about containing following properties:

- name
- type(A/B)
- status(0/1)

Now `status` of all objects contain `null` so i want to set 0 if type is A , and 1 if type is B, hence come to simple looping of Array of Objects as well as modifying them while looping , How to do this?

**Edit:**

Code and table details are given below

```
Table `test`:

Name| Type| status
Ali | A   | NULL
Zeeshan| A | NULL
Waqar| B | NULL


$query = $this->db->query("SELECT test.name as name,test.type as type , test.status as status FROM test");

$some = $query->result();
```

Comment: will you please provide your database query ? and more please add your code also to get the more information

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an UPDATE statement. Since you didn't specify which version of SQL you are using, I can list some links to documentation for UPDATE for several common database versions:

- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)
- [PostGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-update.html)
- [SQL SERVER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

And you should be able to set the value for *status* conditionally using a [CASE statement](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-case/):

```
UPDATE test 
SET status = CASE type WHEN 'A' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

You can see this in action on this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fa170/1).